# Switching between tabs inside of a web application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm making a web application for the administration of a restaurant kind of type. The purpose of this application is to make customers, and the orders of those customers, which has products in it, etc...

This application is written in PHP combined with jQuery.

I have many tabs, such as:

- Displaying the orders
- A screen to make a new order (same  `div` as displaying the list from the orders)
- A screen to show you all products, which you can click on to put them inside of a orders.
- A screen where more order information appears whenever clicking on it.

On this moment, I'm using this kind of snippets to manage this:

```
if (orderListScreen.css('visibility', 'hidden')) {
    orderListScreen.css("visibility", "visible");
    newOrderScreen.css("visibility", "hidden");
}

if (availableProductsScreen.css("visibility", "hidden")) {
    availableProductsScreen.css("visibility", "hidden");
    orderInformationScreen.css("visibility", "visible");
}
```

- Note: This is one block of code.
- Note: the `orderListScreen` and all the other variables refer to different `div` elements.

**Problem**

- This is very confusing to work with.
- This takes me more time to actually think which one is active and which one is not.

---

**My own try**

I've made a small function which also switches between the `visibility` of the elements, but I still don't like it; it makes it too confusing.

```
function switchTab(activate, deactivate) {
    var _activate = $(activate);
    var _deactivate = $(deactivate);

    if (_activate.css("visibility", "hidden")) {
        _activate.css("visibility", "visible");
        _deactivate.css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect that `if` statement to do? Are you sure that's what you want? It doesn't seem right...

Comment: @elclanrs Checking if it actually is `hidden`? But you're right, it probably isn't right.

Comment: I feel that this question is slightly off-topic, since it is more about looking for an alternative, rather then a review of the code. PS: to the OP: have you considered using jQ's `$.toggle()`?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I was'nt ment to make you guys actually search for an alternative for the `visibility` it was just a try of my own. Wich didnt work out that well.

Also, no i didnt, do you mean that that i'll give an `.active` class to the `div` that currently is active?

Comment: @Bas: No, with `$.toggle` you can do something like: `var elem = $('#foo'); elem.toggle(); elem.toggle();` the first `toggle` call will hide the element (or show it, in case it was hidden), the second will do the opposite. It all depends on the element being visible or not

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement doesn't do what you think it does.

Optional details about the `.css()` function:

> The `.css()` function is overloaded in a number of ways. It can take one string, two strings, or an object.
>
>  In the first form, it returns the current value of the specified property. This will probably not be exactly as you specified it. For example, `$("body").css("background-color", "red").css("background-color")` returns `"rgb(255, 0, 0)"` for me.
>
>  In the second, it sets the specified property (first string) to the given value, and returns the jQuery object. In the third, it sets the specified properties (given as keys of the object) to their respective values. This form also returns the jQuery object, for more method chaining.
>
>  As you can see, if you're intent on using the `.css()` function to check a value, the first form is what you want.

A better way of checking visibility would be to use the `.is()` function in conjunction with the `:visible` selector.

Here's my revision. I took the liberty of renaming the parameters. I also used the common practice of naming jQuery variables using [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).

```
function switchTab(toActivate, toDeactivate) {
    var $toActivate = $(toActivate);
    var $toDeactivate = $(toDeactivate);

    if (!$toActivate.is(":visible")) {
        $toActivate.css("visibility", "visible");
        $toDeactivate.css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
}
```

---

Another way:

If there's some common selector between the tabs (for example, if they all have the class `.tab`) and you're fine with `display: none;` instead of `visibility: hidden;`, you can simplify to the following:

```
function switchTab(toActivate) {
    $(".tab").hide();
    $(toActivate).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time :) ill look at it tommorow when i get back on my computer

Comment: Thanks for the optimization on my own try, but i still dont like the idea with toggling the `visibility`'s manually. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @Bas I've listed an alternative in an edit.